# Ajax pushing ' through

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've created a local application which uses ajax to call results from a SQL database.

The system works great, however if some searches with a ' then the system fails and I get the following error "Notice: Array to string conversion in.."

Here's my Javascript which calls the ajax and pushes the results to the div on my HTML page.

Is there a way I can parse the ' with my code below?

```
$('input#prodsearch').keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) { // the enter key
        var name = $('input#prodsearch').val();
        if ($.trim(name) != '') {
            $.post('assets/ajax/prodsearch.php', { prodsearch: name }, function(data) {
                $('#stockresults').html(data)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Heres my php minus the while statement that outputs the rows of results.

```
if (isset($_POST['prodsearch']) === true && empty($_POST['prodsearch']) === false) {

    $query = "SELECT     STKCODE, STKNAME
FROM         dbo.STOCK
WHERE    (STKNAME LIKE '%" . $_POST['prodsearch'] . "%' OR STKCODE LIKE '" . $_POST['prodsearch'] . "%')
order by STKCODE ASC";  

};
```

Comment: Can you also add PHP code

Comment: `{ prodsearch: encodeURIComponent(name) }`

Comment: I've added php code now :)

Comment: Your query is open to SQL Injection. You need to prepare your statements or at least sanitize the inputs!

Comment: Thanks for the concern @BenPearlKahan I'm aware it's open to SQL injection but this is an internal application used by those only searching a product code. I will however add this level of protection shortly.

Comment: an '-character breaks your application. So pls fix the sql injection problems and your problem from above is also fixed.

Comment: 'Notice: Array to string conversion in' means you are treating a array like string or variable. Post the remaining php such that I can help you where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'll want to encode the string(s) you're sending through via AJAX.

Change this line:

```
$.post('assets/ajax/prodsearch.php', { prodsearch: name }, function(data) {
```

to this:

```
$.post('assets/ajax/prodsearch.php', { prodsearch: encodeURIComponent(name) }, function(data) {
```

[More info on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

Comment: if jquerys $.post() function is used with an object instead of a parameterstrig the escape is implicit. You don't have to do this manualy.